# How to invoke a method from one component to other component(in new tab) in react js

Tags: reactjs, web-applications, components

In my application,we are using hash router and rendering a BillingManagement component in a new window by using window.open as follow

```
winObj = window.open('#/BillingManagement');
        var that = this;
        winObj.onclick = function (event) {
            if (event.target.id === "someID") {
                that.currentWindowLogOut();
            }
        }
```

I want to invoke a method of this component from BillingManagement window.it is worked fine for me when BillingManagement window is not refreshed.how to invoke a method from Billingmanagement window and vise versa.